# Submit a form in an AJAX function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

The server side methods works, and the AJAX function sets `data-duplicated="false"`  but `$this.submit();` doesn't work. To actually submit the form I need to press the sumbit button again.

```
<form data-url="/.../" data-duplicated="true" onsubmit="return checkForDuplicates(this)">
   <!-- Form inputs -->
</form>
```

```
function checkForDuplicates(e) {
        var $this = $(e);
        var url = $this.attr('data-url');

        if ($this.attr('data-duplicated') === 'true') {

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result === true) {
                        $this.attr('data-duplicated', 'false');
                        $this.submit();
                    } else {
                        // warrning
                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

What should I do to actually submit the form?

Comment: Try this : `$this[0].submit();`

Comment: If you are using `ajax`, why are you submitting `form` ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH - this[0].submit is not a function.

Comment: @Rayon - I want to check for duplicates, if they exist I don't want to submit the form. Otherwise, it should be submitted.

Comment: @Bacchus, then what you're saying is a wrong approach.

Comment: @Ionut - I check for duplicates in PHP, but I don't want the refresh if there are duplicates.

Comment: If you don't want to refresh the page, don't submit your form in the success function. Use an anchor instead of a submit button in your form. And on click of that anchor do your $.ajax. And get rid of onsubmit from the form. Is useless.

Comment: @Ionut - Again, I don't want to submit IF there are duplicates, otherwise, the form should be submitted.

Comment: @Bacchus, do exactly what I said above and on your ajax response return a message from PHP, let's say "duplicate" if is duplicate, and 'ok' if not duplicate. And in your AJAX success do an if else statement based on your receveid message you submit the form or not. More clear and specific than that I can't be. Hope it helps.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139365/submit-a-form-in-an-ajax-function/38139507#38139507 I have updated the code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bacchus, as I explained in the comments, you can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#submit').on('click', function(){
         $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                   if(result == 'duplicate'){
                     $('#form').submit();
                   }else{
                     //your custom message here
                   }
                }
            });
       });
});
```

```html
<form id='form' action='' method='post'>
  <!--your inputs here-->
  <a id='submit'>Submit form</a>
</form>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: duplicate check should be before submit

Comment: Would be checked on submit using PHP. Why the downvote? This is a perfectly working solution.

Comment: downvote because author want to check duplicate before submit

Comment: @СеменихинМаксим, he already said he checks for duplicates in PHP. Check the comments between me and him on his question and please retrieve you downvote.

Answer (score 0):

**[demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/896fqeka/3/)**

**JavaScript code**

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  checkForDuplicates(this);
})

function checkForDuplicates(e) {
  var _form = $(e).closest('form');
  var url = _form.attr('data-url');

  if (_form.attr('data-duplicated') === 'true') {
    var data = {};
    var url = '/';
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      success: function(result) {
        if (result === true) {
          _form.attr('data-duplicated', 'false');
          _form.trigger('submit');
        } else {
          // warrning
        }
      }
    });

  }
}
```

**HTML code:**

```html
<form data-url="/.../" data-duplicated="true">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The code works exactly the same as mine but now the form is not submitted even when I click on the submit button the second time(I guess .trigger('submit') doesn't work).

Comment: trigger should work, you doing somethings wrong. You can change trigger to _form.submit() but its same